# How to add two Google charts on the one page?

Tags: javascript, charts

## What I've done

I've added Google chart to the head of my page. This returns an image of a chart.

## What I need to do

I simply need to add a second chart to the same page.

## The problem

The code for the second chart is ignored. I largely suspect this is due to me incorrectly combining the code for each chart.

## The code

**First chart (line):**

```
    <!--Load the AJAX API-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

  // Load the Visualization API and the piechart package.
  google.load('visualization', '1.0', {'packages':['corechart']});

  // Set a callback to run when the Google Visualization API is loaded.
  google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

  // Callback that creates and populates a data table,
  // instantiates the pie chart, passes in the data and
  // draws it.
  function drawChart() {

    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('string', 'Month');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Apples');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Oranges');
    data.addRows([
      ['Oct 11', 20, 0],
      ['Nov 11', 0, 0],
      ['Dec 12',  0, 20],
      ['Jan 12', 0, 10],
      ['Feb 12', 0, 10],
      ['March 12', 10, 10]
    ]);

    // Set chart options
    var options = {'width':960,
                   'height':300};

    // Instantiate and draw our chart, passing in some options.
    var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('line_chart'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
  }

</script>
```

**Second chart (pie):**

```
    <!--Load the AJAX API-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

  // Load the Visualization API and the piechart package.
  google.load('visualization', '1.0', {'packages':['corechart']});

  // Set a callback to run when the Google Visualization API is loaded.
  google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

  // Callback that creates and populates a data table,
  // instantiates the pie chart, passes in the data and
  // draws it.
  function drawChart() {

    // Create the data table.
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('string', 'Topping');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Slices');
    data.addRows([
      ['Mushrooms', 3],
      ['Onions', 1],
      ['Olives', 1],
      ['Zucchini', 1],
      ['Pepperoni', 2]
    ]);

    // Set chart options
    var options = {'title':'How Much Pizza I Ate Last Night',
                   'width':400,
                   'height':300};

    // Instantiate and draw our chart, passing in some options.
    var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
  }
</script>
```

Each of the charts are called in the body using a container div with a unique id:

```
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

## My question

How do I stitch these two blocks of code together? I've tried copying drawChart() and specifying unique function names and variables but to no avail.

Comment: You should post your solution as an answer, not an edit to your question. It's perfectly fine to answer your own question.

Comment: @Kevin Reid - I reposted the solution as an answer. I'm restricted to waiting two days to select my own answer as the accepted answer. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: I had a problem with this and discovered it was because my div element was written as <div ... /> instead of explicit begin/end elements <div ...></div>.  If someone else has a problem rendering more than one chart, check that.

Comment: [The Best Easy Solution](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/basic_multiple_charts)

Answer (score 71, accepted):

## Solution

I now have a working solution. It involved discerning which parts of the example code to duplicate and what not to duplicate (as suggested by Oofpez). The data, options and chart variables for EACH of your charts are defined within the ONE drawChart() function.

Here is a working example (just copy and paste into a HTML document):

*...This example further demonstrates how to combine different chart types i.e. pie and line...*

```
<html>
      <head>
        <!--Load the AJAX API-->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">

          // Load the Visualization API and the piechart package.
          google.load('visualization', '1.0', {'packages':['corechart']});

          // Set a callback to run when the Google Visualization API is loaded.
          google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

          // Callback that creates and populates a data table,
          // instantiates the pie chart, passes in the data and
          // draws it.
          function drawChart() {

            // Create the data table.
            var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
            data.addColumn('string', 'Topping');    
            data.addColumn('number', 'Slices');
            data.addRows([
              ['Mushrooms', 3],
              ['Onions', 1],
              ['Olives', 1],
              ['Zucchini', 1],
              ['Pepperoni', 2]
            ]);
            // Create the data table.
            var data2 = new google.visualization.DataTable();
            data2.addColumn('string', 'Topping');
            data2.addColumn('number', 'Slices');
            data2.addRows([
              ['Mushrooms', 3],
              ['Onions', 1],
              ['Olives', 15],
              ['Zucchini', 1],
              ['Pepperoni', 2]
            ]);

            var data3 = new google.visualization.DataTable();
            data3.addColumn('string', 'Year');
            data3.addColumn('number', 'Sales');
            data3.addColumn('number', 'Expenses');
            data3.addRows([
              ['2004', 1000, 400],
              ['2005', 1170, 460],
              ['2006',  860, 580],
              ['2007', 1030, 540]
            ]);

            // Set chart options
            var options = {'title':'How Much Pizza I Ate Last Night',
                           'width':400,
                           'height':300};
            // Set chart options
            var options2 = {'title':'How Much Pizza You Ate Last Night',
                           'width':400,
                           'height':300};
            // Set chart options
            var options3 = {'title':'Line chart',
                           'width':400,
                           'height':300};

            // Instantiate and draw our chart, passing in some options.
            var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
            chart.draw(data, options);
            var chart2 = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('chart_div2'));
            chart2.draw(data2, options2);
            var chart3 = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div3'));
            chart3.draw(data3, options3);

          }
        </script>
      </head>

      <body>
        <!--Divs that will hold the charts-->
        <div id="chart_div"></div>
        <div id="chart_div2"></div>
        <div id="chart_div3"></div>
      </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: this only works if you know how many charts you're going to have at any given time, though.

Comment: @avoliva please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34662223/multiple-google-visualization-table-on-one-page

Answer (score 14):

Basically you can wrap function `drawChart` for parameters to pass on like:

```
function drawChart(chartType, containerID, dataArray, options)
```

and

```
call google.setOnLoadCallback(function() {
    drawChart('barChart', 'div_id_1', test_array, null);
});
```

as many times as much you want to render graphs:

```
var test_array = [
    ['Name', 'Count-A', 'Count-B'],
    ['Test-A', 4, 3],
    ['Test-B', 1, 2],
    ['Test-C', 3, 4],
    ['Test-D', 2, 0],
    ['Test-E', 2, 5]
];

google.load("visualization", "1", {packages: ["corechart",'table']});

google.setOnLoadCallback(function() {
    drawChart('barChart', 'div_id_1', test_array, null);
});

google.setOnLoadCallback(function() {
    drawChart('columnChart', 'div_id_2', test_array, null);
});


function drawChart(chartType, containerID, dataArray, options) {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(dataArray);
    var containerDiv = document.getElementById(containerID);
    var chart = false;

    if (chartType.toUpperCase() == 'BARCHART') {
        chart = new google.visualization.BarChart(containerDiv);
    }
    else if (chartType.toUpperCase() == 'COLUMNCHART') {
        chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(containerDiv);
    }
    else if (chartType.toUpperCase() == 'PIECHART') {
        chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(containerDiv);
    }
    else if (chartType.toUpperCase() == 'TABLECHART')
    {
        chart = new google.visualization.Table(containerDiv);
    }

    if (chart == false) {
        return false;
    }

    chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

Comment: This is the route I chose, but found it would not work with the new Material Line charts. Works fine with classic. With material, which chart shows up is different on each refresh :)

Comment: a JSfiddle example would be go a long way.

Answer (score 5):

Based on @Dominor's answer, but if you are registering your charts from arbitrary, just build a function stack that gets executed in the callback function like so:

```
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

// Callback that creates and populates a data table,
// instantiates the pie chart, passes in the data and
// draws it.
googleChartStack = [];

function drawChart() {
    for (var i = googleChartStack.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        googleChartStack[i]();
    }
}
```

Then, somewhere else in your template, you can push to this stack. In my example, I was iterating through some template snippet.

```
<script>
  googleChartStack.push(function() {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['A', 'B'],
      ['A', 1],
      ['B', 2]
    ]);

    var options = {
      title: 'none',
      legend: 'none'
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById("relevant-id"));
    chart.draw(data, options);          
  })
</script>
```

Comment: This is close to what I ended up doing. I was coming here to post my work, but instead I'll upvote yours since it captures the same spirit. Build a stack of google charts, then load them all at once.

Answer (score 5):

Production version of Google Charts has a timing bug that prevents more than one chart from loading on the same page.

Google fixed this in a recent release, available with the frozen version loader: https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/library_loading_enhancements#frozen-versions

Relevant thread: https://groups.google.com/forum/?utm_medium=email&utm_source=footer#!msg/google-visualization-api/KulpuT418cg/yZieM8buCQAJ

Comment: I knew this was a google bug. This has saved me hours.

Answer (score 4):

maybe when you specify

```
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
```

twice it overwrites the callback event for the first time?

Just a guess...

Comment: Thanks. It was. I figured out how to avoid having to use that function twice. Refer to my original post for a full explanation of the solution.

Answer (score 4):

in above answer package for only pie is added..for printing pie and line chart on the same page we must include line package also: 
google.load('visualization', '1.0', {'packages':['corechart','line']});

full code:-

```
      // Load the Visualization API and the piechart package.
      google.load('visualization', '1.0', {'packages':['corechart','line']});

      // Set a callback to run when the Google Visualization API is loaded.
      google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

      // Callback that creates and populates a data table,
      // instantiates the pie chart, passes in the data and
      // draws it.
      function drawChart() {

        // Create the data table.
        var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
        data.addColumn('string', 'Topping');    
        data.addColumn('number', 'Slices');
        data.addRows([
          ['Mushrooms', 3],
          ['Onions', 1],
          ['Olives', 1],
          ['Zucchini', 1],
          ['Pepperoni', 2]
        ]);
        // Create the data table.
        var data2 = new google.visualization.DataTable();
        data2.addColumn('string', 'Topping');
        data2.addColumn('number', 'Slices');
        data2.addRows([
          ['Mushrooms', 3],
          ['Onions', 1],
          ['Olives', 15],
          ['Zucchini', 1],
          ['Pepperoni', 2]
        ]);

        var data3 = new google.visualization.DataTable();
        data3.addColumn('string', 'Year');
        data3.addColumn('number', 'Sales');
        data3.addColumn('number', 'Expenses');
        data3.addRows([
          ['2004', 1000, 400],
          ['2005', 1170, 460],
          ['2006',  860, 580],
          ['2007', 1030, 540]
        ]);

        // Set chart options
        var options = {'title':'How Much Pizza I Ate Last Night',
                       'width':400,
                       'height':300};
        // Set chart options
        var options2 = {'title':'How Much Pizza You Ate Last Night',
                       'width':400,
                       'height':300};
        // Set chart options
        var options3 = {'title':'Line chart',
                       'width':400,
                       'height':300};

        // Instantiate and draw our chart, passing in some options.
        var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
        chart.draw(data, options);
        var chart2 = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('chart_div2'));
        chart2.draw(data2, options2);
        var chart3 = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div3'));
        chart3.draw(data3, options3);

      }
    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <!--Divs that will hold the charts-->
    <div id="chart_div"></div>
    <div id="chart_div2"></div>
    <div id="chart_div3"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do is have a function for each chart. Then do

```
google.setOnLoadCallback(initialize);
```

and have initialize call each function to create the chart. It is a lot cleaner that way than drawing multiple charts in one function. It also will help debugging as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  google.load("visualization", "1.1", {packages:["bar"]});
  google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
  function drawChart() {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['Day/Month', 'Sales', 'Goal'],
      ['Daily', 33549.17,47328.04],
      ['M-T-D', 96114.18,141984.12]
    ]);


    var data1 = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['Day/Month', 'Bookings', 'Goal'],

      ['Daily', 37991.21,47659.09],

      ['M-T-D', 95610.47,142977.27]

    ]);
   var options = {
  colors: ['#e0aa0e', '#ecbb6e','green'],
      width: 800,
      chart: {
        title: 'Test Company Sales',
        subtitle: 'Sales vs Goal',
      }
    };
    var options1 = {
  colors: ['#e0440e', '#ec8f6e','green'],
      width: 800,
      chart: {
        title: 'Test Company Bookings',
        subtitle: 'Bookings',
      }
    };

    var chart = new google.charts.Bar(document.getElementById('sales'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
    var chart2 = new google.charts.Bar(document.getElementById('bookings'));

    chart2.draw(data1, options1);
  }
</script>





  <div style="display: table; width: 100%;">
      <div style="display: table-row">
           <div id="sales" style="width: 900px; height: 500px; display: table-cell;"></div>
          <div id="bookings" style="width: 900px; height: 500px; display: table-cell;"></div>
     </div>
</div>
```

Comment: i cant get the above code to render both graphs at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

step_1.(change id curve_chart to some another name(eg.ajay))

```
<body>
<div id="ajay" style="width: 900px; height: 500px"></div>
```

step_2.(assign this id to your chart in script element)..

```
    var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('ajay'));

    chart.draw(data, options);
  }
</script>
```