# Django put forloop.counter0 into custom tag argument list possible?

Tags: django, google-visualization, django-templates

So I am using django-google-charts to generate bar chart. Here the chart is drawn in the "out" div.
However I want to generate more than one charts in one page, within different div, for example chart0 in "out0", chart1 in "out1", chart2 in "out2".

```
{% load googlecharts %}
<div id="out"></div>
{% googlecharts %}
    {# some code here #}
    {% graph "out" "out_data" "out_options" %}
{% endgooglecharts %}
```

So I tried to modify the `{% graph "out" "out_data" "out_options" %}`, my intention was
`{% graph out|add:{{ forloop.counter0 }} "out_data" "out_options" %}` so that graph output source will be replaced by out0, out1, out2, etc.

However the use of  {{}} inside {{%%}} is not allowed. Plus the graph tag will take whatever at the first place as a string parameter as separated by comma.

Is it possible to solve the problem on the template side?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

```
{% graph "out"|add:forloop.counter0  "out_data" "out_options" %}
```

no brackets inside {% %} and it should work

also: |add concatenates strings, you were concatenating a variable (out instead of "out")
the above code should now work as you expect :)

Comment: sorry, that was my mistake. I should put a double quote around. I tried you method, but still failed. The html file rendered is `opt.container = ""out"|add:forloop.counter0"`

Comment: as i said, the it will just take the first argument as whatever it is. btw why you didn't put curly brackets around the `forloop.counter0`?

Comment: you have to use {% %} and {{ }} so that django knows how to process them (otherwise you'll get only strings). {{ var }} identifies a single variable from the context, {% if var %} identifies an if statement and the "var" will be extracted from the context aswell, see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/templates/

Comment: for the other problem, i don't actually know, i just checked the source code from git, and that templatetag does no string conversion whatsoever...

Comment: thank you very much. do you how to solve this very strange problem?

Comment: maybe this requires a lot of tinkering, but it's worth a try: you could create your own templatetag to wrap the api one. This templatetag should then return the graph object created by that api, with the variables you pass it from within the for loop. or you could consider using the googlechart js api. or write to the developer of the lib you're using :)

Comment: Thank you. You are so right. Maybe I just switch to js api or write to the developer.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I worked out fine using only the google chart tools Javasciprt API. It allows multiple charts on one page. Similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9888920/how-to-add-two-google-charts-on-the-one-page). The last answer is the solution.