# Google charts Container is not defined.. But the div is there

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

My JS on a page POSTs to a chart generation PHP script, and what the PHP script returns is then added to the page (.html() of an div). However, using the Google Charts API.. the page is blank. I get the error Container is not defined from google's library. Here's what the PHP script is passing:

```
<script>google.load('visualization', '1', {packages: ['corechart']});
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
    function drawChart() {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
        ['Date', 'BTC Price'],['2013-02-12', 22.5]
    ]);
    alert(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    chart.draw(data, {title: 'BTC/USD price'});
    }</script><div id='chart_div' style='width: 900px; height: 500px;'></div>
```

Why would document.getElementByID return null when chartContent is there?'

**EDIT**: Now the alert does not show up, yet the page is still blank.

Comment: Here is solution 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9888920/how-to-add-two-google-charts-on-the-one-page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to wait for data load from google.
Check api  documentation,
in first example there's
`google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);`
instead of `drawChart()`

You're calling drawChart too early, 
before drawchart's are loaded

Comment: It is not that, I had that at first and it had the same behavior

Comment: this answer is not the situation in my case

Comment: @gladsocc this answer is not correct, why did you accept it?