# Array an array one minute and not the next? Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Tags: php

For some reason my code is an array one minute and not the next. I'm just learning php and I can't figure this out. I've used this page to figure most of this out: [How to add two Google charts on the one page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9888920/how-to-add-two-google-charts-on-the-one-page)

My code is also used on a page that shows the data as a table. On that page it works fine....but for some reason I'm getting **Invalid argument supplied for foreach()** on the pie charts page...and it's saying it's not an array. I'm not sure how to go about fixing this.

The url I'm using is ?action=scores&data=pie so it should list all of the universities in "get_universities()" (there's 3 there).

Can anyone help please?

The switch:

```
// Showing scores   
case 'scores':
    // Grab the Uni ID and use the appropriate query
    if (isset($_GET['uni_id']))
    {
        $uni_id = $_GET['uni_id'];
        $uni = get_university($uni_id);
    }
    else
    {
        $uni = get_universities();
    }

    // We have to display this data according to the request
    if (isset($_GET['data']))
    {
        $data = $_GET['data'];
    }
    else
    {
        $data = "table";
    }

    // Display the data accordingly
    include (root . '/view/' . $data . '_view.php');

    break;
```

The pie graphs:

```
    // Create the data table.
    <?php foreach ($uni as $uni) : ?>
    var data<?php echo $uni['university_id']; ?> = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data<?php echo $uni['university_id']; ?>.addColumn('string', 'Area');
    data<?php echo $uni['university_id']; ?>.addColumn('number', 'Score');
    data<?php echo $uni['university_id']; ?>.addRows([
      ['Teaching', <?php echo $uni['teaching_score']; ?>],
      ['Intl Outlook', <?php echo $uni['int_outlook_score']; ?>],
      ['Industry Income', <?php echo $uni['ind_income_score']; ?>],
      ['Research', <?php echo $uni['research_score']; ?>],
      ['Citations', <?php echo $uni['citations_score']; ?>]
    ]);
    <?php endforeach ?>

    // Set chart options
    <?php foreach ($uni as $uni) : ?>
    var options<?php echo $uni['university_id']; ?> = {'title':'<?php echo $uni['university_name']; ?> Scores',
                   'width':400,
                   'height':300};
    <?php endforeach ?>

    // Instantiate and draw our chart, passing in some options.
    <?php foreach ($uni as $uni) : ?>
    var chart<?php echo $uni['university_id']; ?> = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('chart_div<?php echo $uni['university_id']; ?>'));
    chart.draw(data<?php echo $uni['university_id']; ?>, options<?php echo $uni['university_id']; ?>);
    <?php endforeach ?>
```

The table view (which works):

```
<?php foreach ($uni as $uni) : ?>
<td>
    <a href="?uni=<?php echo $uni['university_id']; ?>">
        <?php echo $uni['university_name']; ?>
    </a>
</td>
<etc>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your `foreach` statement:

```
foreach ($uni as $uni) :
```

Here you override the `$uni` variable. Use different names for the collection and item, eg:

```
foreach ($uni as $theUni) :
// also change instances of $uni below
```

**EDIT**

The above is **wrong**. The parsing of the first parameter of `foreach` happens only once so in *that* `foreach` it won't be a problem. However a `foreach` is not a new scope, so if you plan to reuse the array variable, you need to choose a different name as the iterator so it won't get overridden.

```
$a = array(); // $a is array
foreach ($a as $a) {
  // $a is element of original $a
}
// $a is the last element of the original $a array

foreach ($a as $a) // Fail, since $a is not an array anymore
```

Comment: But I do that in the table view without any issues.