# Google Charts stops drawing after first chart

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

### What I want to do

Show multiple Barcharts on one Page

### What I already did

The Barcharts have prevously been Linecharts.
As Linecharts I could show two Charts on the same page without a problem.
I used two seperate drawChart()-functions for them.
I then converted the charts to Barcharts (material design).
Now it only shows one chart.
I already searched for an answer and found this: [How to add two Google charts on the one page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9888920/how-to-add-two-google-charts-on-the-one-page)
I follow this and it still doesn't work.

### My Code

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    google.load("visualization", "1.1", {
        packages: ["Bar"]
    });
    google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

    function drawChart() {

        var data1 = new google.visualization.DataTable();
        data1.addColumn("string", "Key1");
        data1.addColumn("number", "Value1");

        data1.addRows([
            ['2015.01', 65.5],
            ['2015.02', 52.6],
            ['2015.03', 45.5],
            ['2015.04', 40.7],
            ['2015.05', 68.7],
            ['2015.06', 56.4],
            ['2015.07', 38.4],
            ['2015.08', 45.2],
            ['2015.09', 45.2],
            ['2015.10', 4.8]
        ]);

        var data2 = new google.visualization.DataTable();
        data2.addColumn("string", "Key2");
        data2.addColumn("number", "Value2");

        data2.addRows([
            ['2015.01', 300.08],
            ['2015.02', 455.08],
            ['2015.03', 454.62],
            ['2015.04', 362.93],
            ['2015.05', 527.12],
            ['2015.06', 588.28],
            ['2015.07', 409.93],
            ['2015.08', 432.08],
            ['2015.09', 462.33],
            ['2015.10', 32.38]
        ]);

        var options = {};

        var chart1 = new google.charts.Bar(document.getElementById("chart_div1"));
        chart1.draw(data1, options);

        var chart2 = new google.charts.Bar(document.getElementById("chart_div2"));
        chart2.draw(data2, options);

    }


</script>

<div id="chart_div1"></div>
<div id="chart_div2"></div>
```

Best viewed here: https://jsfiddle.net/yrzf3v97/

### The Problem

It only shows one chart. Most of the tme its the first but in sometimes its the second one.
By using the alert()-function it can confirm that the code runs until the end.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems this behavior is related with `draw` function. In particular, the second chart is not rendered since *chart SVG is not getting generated* after `draw` function is invoked for the second time.

According to [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/basic_draw_chart):

> The draw() method is asynchronous: that is, it returns immediately,
>   but the instance that it returns might not be immediately available.

For rendering multiple charts on the page you could consider the following approach: *render the next chart once the previous one is rendered*, for example:

```
var chart1 = new google.charts.Bar(document.getElementById("chart_div1"));
google.visualization.events.addOneTimeListener(chart1, 'ready', function(){
     //render chart2 once chart1 is rendered
     var chart2 = new google.charts.Bar(document.getElementById("chart_div2"));
     chart2.draw(data2, options);     
});
chart1.draw(data1, options);
```

**Complete example**

```js
google.load("visualization", "1.1", { packages: ["Bar"] });
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

function drawChart() {

    var data1 = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data1.addColumn("string", "Key1");
    data1.addColumn("number", "Value1");

    data1.addRows([['2015.01', 65.5],
        ['2015.02', 52.6],
        ['2015.03', 45.5],
        ['2015.04', 40.7],
        ['2015.05', 68.7],
        ['2015.06', 56.4],
        ['2015.07', 38.4],
        ['2015.08', 45.2],
        ['2015.09', 45.2],
        ['2015.10', 4.8]]);

    var data2 = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data2.addColumn("string", "Key2");
    data2.addColumn("number", "Value2");

    data2.addRows([['2015.01', 300.08],
        ['2015.02', 455.08],
        ['2015.03', 454.62],
        ['2015.04', 362.93],
        ['2015.05', 527.12],
        ['2015.06', 588.28],
        ['2015.07', 409.93],
        ['2015.08', 432.08],
        ['2015.09', 462.33],
        ['2015.10', 32.38]]);

    var options = {};
    drawCharts([{id: 'chart_div1', data: data1, options: options},{id: 'chart_div2', data: data2, options: options}]);
}



function drawCharts(chartsOptions,index)
{
    var curIndex = index || 0;
    var chartOptions = chartsOptions[curIndex];
    var chart = new google.charts.Bar(document.getElementById(chartOptions.id));
    google.visualization.events.addOneTimeListener(chart, 'ready', function(){
       if(curIndex < chartsOptions.length - 1)
          drawCharts(chartsOptions,curIndex+1);
    });
    chart.draw(chartOptions.data, chartOptions.options);
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<div id="chart_div1"></div>
<div id="chart_div2"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for this - I too only started experiencing this issue from today. Google must have made changes to both 1.0 and 1.1 versions.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone who runs into this problem in 2016, you may have code like I did which referred to an older version of Google Charts. Update your references to follow the latest guidelines at https://developers.google.com/chart. In my case, the following line-for-line changes fixed the issue:

old:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
google.load('visualization', '1.1', {'packages':['bar']});
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawCharts);
var chart = new google.charts.Bar(document.getElementById('myDivId'));
chart.draw(data, google.charts.Bar.convertOptions(options));
```

new:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
google.charts.load('current', {packages:['corechart']});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawCharts);
var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('myDivId'));
chart.draw(data, options);
```