# Multiple Google Charts

Tags: javascript, html, charts, google-visualization

I am attempting to create multiple Google Charts, but I can't get it to work. I've tried everything I could find on Stack Overflow. I most recently attempted [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9888920/how-to-add-two-google-charts-on-the-one-page) fix, but it didn't work. I think I may be missing something. Can anyone see anything wrong with the code as it stands now?

**Expected Behavior:**

*Page displays bar graph. Then, a line graph is displayed underneath the bar graph.*

**Current Behavior:**

*Page displays bar graph. Line graph does not display.*

Here is [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/db9ekod9/2/). On a side note, the JavaScript only seems to work inline on JSFiddle. If I moved it into the JavaScript section, it did not function properly. Maybe this has something to do with the external resource that was called?

Regardless, I am currently doing this all inline for this experiment.

**HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://www.google.com/jsapi" type="text/javascript">
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    // Load the Visualization API and the chart packages.
    google.load('visualization', '1.1', {
        packages: ['line', 'bar', 'corechart']
    });
    // Set a callback to run when the Google Visualization API is loaded.
    google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
    // Callback that creates and populates a data table,
    // instantiates the charts, passes in the data and
    // draws them.
    function drawChart() {
        // Create the data table.
        var BarData = new google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
            ['', 'Customer', 'Segment Avg'],
            ['TTM Sales', 4, 2],
            ['TTM Orders', 5, 3],
            ['TTM Categories', 7, 4]
        ]);
        // Create the data table.
        var LineData = new google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
            ['Year', 'Customer', 'Segment Avg'],
            ['2011', 4, 5],
            ['2012', 5, 3],
            ['2013', 4, 2]
        ]);
        // Set chart options
        var BarOptions = {
            chart: {
                title: 'Performance',
            },
            width: 900,
            height: 500
        };
        // Set chart options
        var LineOptions = {
            chart: {
                title: 'Sales History'
            },
            width: 900,
            height: 500
        };
        // Instantiate and draw our chart, passing in some options.
        var BarChart = new google.charts.Bar(document.getElementById(
            'bar_chart'));
        BarChart.draw(BarData, BarOptions);
        var LineChart = new google.charts.Line(document.getElementById(
            'line_chart'));
        LineChart.draw(LineData, LineOptions);
    };
    </script>
    <title>Test Chart Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <!--Divs that will hold the charts-->
    <div id="bar_chart"></div>
    <div id="line_chart"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: the issue is related to timing. here is working fork of your fiddle with timeout separating the execution of the two charts. https://jsfiddle.net/m7mn72e2/

Comment: note also that in the failing test case, child elements are added by googlecharts code to both divs.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It seems some changes have been made in the latest version of Google Charts API that causes this behavior, but there is a reliable way to render multiple charts on a single page. The idea is to render the next chart once the previous one is rendered, for that purpose you could utilize `ready` event handler.

Having said that, replace

```
var barChart = new google.charts.Bar(document.getElementById('bar_chart'));
barChart.draw(barData, barOptions);
var lineChart = new google.charts.Line(document.getElementById('line_chart'));
lineChart.draw(lineData, lineOptions);
```

with

```
var barChart = new google.charts.Bar(document.getElementById('bar_chart'));
google.visualization.events.addOneTimeListener(barChart, 'ready', function () {
      var lineChart = new google.charts.Line(document.getElementById('line_chart'));
      lineChart.draw(lineData, lineOptions);
});
barChart.draw(barData, barOptions);
```

**Working example**

```js
google.load('visualization', '1.1', {
        packages: ['line', 'bar', 'corechart']
    });
    // Set a callback to run when the Google Visualization API is loaded.
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawCharts);

function drawCharts() {
    // Create the data table.
    var barData = new google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
        ['', 'Customer', 'Segment Avg'],
        ['TTM Sales', 4, 2],
        ['TTM Orders', 5, 3],
        ['TTM Categories', 7, 4]
    ]);
    // Create the data table.
    var lineData = new google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
        ['Year', 'Customer', 'Segment Avg'],
        ['2011', 4, 5],
        ['2012', 5, 3],
        ['2013', 4, 2]
    ]);
    // Set chart options
    var barOptions = {
        chart: {
            title: 'Performance',
        },
        width: 900,
        height: 500
    };
    // Set chart options
    var lineOptions = {
        chart: {
            title: 'Sales History'
        },
        width: 900,
        height: 500
    };


    var barChart = new google.charts.Bar(document.getElementById('bar_chart'));
    google.visualization.events.addOneTimeListener(barChart, 'ready', function () {
        var lineChart = new google.charts.Line(document.getElementById('line_chart'));
        lineChart.draw(lineData, lineOptions);
    });
    barChart.draw(barData, barOptions);
};
```

```html
<script src="https://www.google.com/jsapi" type="text/javascript"></script>
<div id="bar_chart"></div>
<div id="line_chart"></div>
```

Comment: Is there a benefit to using this method as opposed to using the setTimeout function?

Comment: In my opinion it is more reliable way .In case of setTimeout there is no guarantee that chart will get rendered since the specified delay does not correspond to the time when first chart is rendered

Answer (score 2):

Works with `setTimeout`:

```
// Instantiate and draw our chart, passing in some options.
var BarChart = new google.charts.Bar(document.getElementById(
    'bar_chart'));
setTimeout(function() {
  BarChart.draw(BarData, BarOptions);
}, 0);
var LineChart = new google.charts.Line(document.getElementById(
    'line_chart'));
setTimeout(function() {
  LineChart.draw(LineData, LineOptions);
}, 1e3);
```

Updated [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/db9ekod9/3/)

Answer (score 1):

The code below works by creating the second chart inside of setTimeout. 
I don't know what is causing the problem, 
 but at least you have a workaround.

**[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/esfdnyhz/)**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    // Load the Visualization API and the chart packages.
    google.load('visualization', '1.1', {
        packages: ['line', 'bar', 'corechart']
    });
    // Set a callback to run when the Google Visualization API is loaded.
    google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
    // Callback that creates and populates a data table,
    // instantiates the charts, passes in the data and
    // draws them.
    function drawChart() {
        // Create the data table.
        var BarData = new google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
            ['', 'Customer', 'Segment Avg'],
            ['TTM Sales', 4, 2],
            ['TTM Orders', 5, 3],
            ['TTM Categories', 7, 4]
        ]);
        // Create the data table.
        var LineData = new google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
            ['Year', 'Customer', 'Segment Avg'],
            ['2011', 4, 5],
            ['2012', 5, 3],
            ['2013', 4, 2]
        ]);
        // Set chart options
        var BarOptions = {
            chart: {
                title: 'Performance',
            },
            width: 900,
            height: 500
        };
        // Set chart options
        var LineOptions = {
            chart: {
                title: 'Sales History'
            },
            width: 900,
            height: 500
        };
        // Instantiate and draw our chart, passing in some options.
        var BarChart = new google.charts.Bar(document.getElementById(
            'bar_chart'));

        var LineChart = new google.charts.Line(document.getElementById(
            'line_chart'));
        LineChart.draw(LineData, LineOptions);
        setTimeout(function(){


        BarChart.draw(BarData, BarOptions);
    },50);

        };
    </script>
    <body>
        <!--Divs that will hold the charts-->
        <div id="bar_chart"></div>
        <div id="line_chart"></div>
    </body>
```

Comment: This is perfect. As I've continued my reading, I've seen a couple of people say that there are issues with multiple charts in Google Charts. But, this definitely takes care of the issue. Thanks!

Comment: I will accept the answer in 5 minutes when it allows me to do so.

Comment: How does this compare to Vadim's solution of using the the ready event handler? I want to ensure that I'm using the best solution. In my head, the ready handler makes more sense, as it is tied directly to the previous function rather than an abstract delay that we select.

Comment: Indeed, the ready handler is a better approach. The timeout was suggested as a workaround until a more precise solution is available.

Answer (score 1):

Google fixed this timing issue in a recent release, available with the frozen version loader:   https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/library_loading_enhancements#frozen-versions

Relevant thread: https://groups.google.com/forum/?utm_medium=email&utm_source=footer#!msg/google-visualization-api/KulpuT418cg/yZieM8buCQAJ