# Multiple Google charts on the same page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-visualization

I'm trying to create a POC of a stock portfolio.
I'm using Google charts to do it.
I want to generate 3 charts: one for each stock (I have two stocks) and one for both of them.
in my html I've created three divs (using some guids)

```
<div id="e480c510499e4bbdaa8ae8e4a1001cd8"></div>
<div id="2dea80b0fabd43bba019dbc3ddf342aa"></div>
<div id="linechart_material"></div>
```

and I've generated a javascript that is supposed to populate the divs

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
$('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
});
google.load('visualization', '1.1', { 'packages': ['line'] });

google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

function drawChart() {
var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
data.addColumn('date', 'Day');

data.addColumn('number', 'Company #4');
data.addColumn('number', 'Company #2');
data.addRow([new Date(2015, 11,  27), 12.7389789250395,4.10950499778125]);
data.addRow([new Date(2015, 11,  26), 6.76681987790708,8.38212726329552]);
data.addRow([new Date(2015, 11,  25), 15.7216755155109,4.36060299741132]);
data.addRow([new Date(2015, 11,  24), 7.44940381844035,3.34093286951116]);
data.addRow([new Date(2015, 11,  23), 9.02574470221333,10.0405249521325]);
data.addRow([new Date(2015, 11,  22), 11.9767397269498,5.29850781210629]);
data.addRow([new Date(2015, 11,  21), 14.5598888055235,6.3867255497662]);
data.addRow([new Date(2015, 11,  20), 12.2693184056642,3.70270192981823]);
data.addRow([new Date(2015, 11,  19), 8.29967047194935,17.0856299675469]);
data.addRow([new Date(2015, 11,  18), 12.9148372020176,4.37814835290338]);
var options = {
title: 'Stock Performance',
width: 900,
height: 500
};

var chart = new google.charts.Line(document.getElementById('linechart_material'));
chart.draw(data, options);

var data0 = new google.visualization.DataTable();
data0.addColumn('date', 'Day');
data0.addColumn('number', 'Company #4');
data0.addRow([new Date(2015, 11,  27), 12.7389789250395]);
data0.addRow([new Date(2015, 11,  26), 6.76681987790708]);
data0.addRow([new Date(2015, 11,  25), 15.7216755155109]);
data0.addRow([new Date(2015, 11,  24), 7.44940381844035]);
data0.addRow([new Date(2015, 11,  23), 9.02574470221333]);
data0.addRow([new Date(2015, 11,  22), 11.9767397269498]);
data0.addRow([new Date(2015, 11,  21), 14.5598888055235]);
data0.addRow([new Date(2015, 11,  20), 12.2693184056642]);
data0.addRow([new Date(2015, 11,  19), 8.29967047194935]);
data0.addRow([new Date(2015, 11,  18), 12.9148372020176]);
var options0 = {
title: 'Stock Performance',
width: 300,
height: 300
};

var chart0 = new google.charts.Line(document.getElementById('e480c510499e4bbdaa8ae8e4a1001cd8'));
chart0.draw(data0, options0);

var data1 = new google.visualization.DataTable();
data1.addColumn('date', 'Day');
data1.addColumn('number', 'Company #2');
data1.addRow([new Date(2015, 11,  27), 4.10950499778125]);
data1.addRow([new Date(2015, 11,  26), 8.38212726329552]);
data1.addRow([new Date(2015, 11,  25), 4.36060299741132]);
data1.addRow([new Date(2015, 11,  24), 3.34093286951116]);
data1.addRow([new Date(2015, 11,  23), 10.0405249521325]);
data1.addRow([new Date(2015, 11,  22), 5.29850781210629]);
data1.addRow([new Date(2015, 11,  21), 6.3867255497662]);
data1.addRow([new Date(2015, 11,  20), 3.70270192981823]);
data1.addRow([new Date(2015, 11,  19), 17.0856299675469]);
data1.addRow([new Date(2015, 11,  18), 4.37814835290338]);
var options1 = {
title: 'Stock Performance',
width: 300,
height: 300
};

var chart1 = new google.charts.Line(document.getElementById('2dea80b0fabd43bba019dbc3ddf342aa'));
chart1.draw(data1, options1);

}
```

The problem is that each time the page loads, only one of the three charts is being rendered. (Each time a different one)
Anyone has ever encountered such issue?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add multiple material google charts to one page?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33712452/how-to-add-multiple-material-google-charts-to-one-page)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The same issue](https://github.com/google/google-visualization-issues/issues/2066) was reported in [google-visualization-issues](https://github.com/google/google-visualization-issues) repository:

> The problems people have seen with the sizing of multiple instances of
>   material charts should be resolved with this new release.   You can
>   change your code to load "1.1" now so that when the candidate release
>   becomes available, you will be using it.

There are at least two solutions available at the moment:

**Option 1. Using the frozen version loader.**

Since

> The rollout of the v43 candidate release that would fix this problem

switch to using the frozen version loader.

Steps:

1)Add a reference to loader: `<script
   src="http://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>`

2)Then load a 43 version of library: `google.charts.load("43",{packages:["line"]});`

3)Replace:

```
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
```

with

```
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
```

**Example**

```js
google.charts.load("43",{packages:["line"]});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

function drawChart() {
var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
data.addColumn('date', 'Day');

data.addColumn('number', 'Company #4');
data.addColumn('number', 'Company #2');
data.addRow([new Date(2015, 11,  27), 12.7389789250395,4.10950499778125]);
data.addRow([new Date(2015, 11,  26), 6.76681987790708,8.38212726329552]);
data.addRow([new Date(2015, 11,  25), 15.7216755155109,4.36060299741132]);
data.addRow([new Date(2015, 11,  24), 7.44940381844035,3.34093286951116]);
data.addRow([new Date(2015, 11,  23), 9.02574470221333,10.0405249521325]);
data.addRow([new Date(2015, 11,  22), 11.9767397269498,5.29850781210629]);
data.addRow([new Date(2015, 11,  21), 14.5598888055235,6.3867255497662]);
data.addRow([new Date(2015, 11,  20), 12.2693184056642,3.70270192981823]);
data.addRow([new Date(2015, 11,  19), 8.29967047194935,17.0856299675469]);
data.addRow([new Date(2015, 11,  18), 12.9148372020176,4.37814835290338]);
var options = {
title: 'Stock Performance',
width: 900,
height: 500
};

var chart = new google.charts.Line(document.getElementById('linechart_material'));
chart.draw(data, options);

var data0 = new google.visualization.DataTable();
data0.addColumn('date', 'Day');
data0.addColumn('number', 'Company #4');
data0.addRow([new Date(2015, 11,  27), 12.7389789250395]);
data0.addRow([new Date(2015, 11,  26), 6.76681987790708]);
data0.addRow([new Date(2015, 11,  25), 15.7216755155109]);
data0.addRow([new Date(2015, 11,  24), 7.44940381844035]);
data0.addRow([new Date(2015, 11,  23), 9.02574470221333]);
data0.addRow([new Date(2015, 11,  22), 11.9767397269498]);
data0.addRow([new Date(2015, 11,  21), 14.5598888055235]);
data0.addRow([new Date(2015, 11,  20), 12.2693184056642]);
data0.addRow([new Date(2015, 11,  19), 8.29967047194935]);
data0.addRow([new Date(2015, 11,  18), 12.9148372020176]);
var options0 = {
title: 'Stock Performance',
width: 300,
height: 300
};

var chart0 = new google.charts.Line(document.getElementById('e480c510499e4bbdaa8ae8e4a1001cd8'));
chart0.draw(data0, options0);

var data1 = new google.visualization.DataTable();
data1.addColumn('date', 'Day');
data1.addColumn('number', 'Company #2');
data1.addRow([new Date(2015, 11,  27), 4.10950499778125]);
data1.addRow([new Date(2015, 11,  26), 8.38212726329552]);
data1.addRow([new Date(2015, 11,  25), 4.36060299741132]);
data1.addRow([new Date(2015, 11,  24), 3.34093286951116]);
data1.addRow([new Date(2015, 11,  23), 10.0405249521325]);
data1.addRow([new Date(2015, 11,  22), 5.29850781210629]);
data1.addRow([new Date(2015, 11,  21), 6.3867255497662]);
data1.addRow([new Date(2015, 11,  20), 3.70270192981823]);
data1.addRow([new Date(2015, 11,  19), 17.0856299675469]);
data1.addRow([new Date(2015, 11,  18), 4.37814835290338]);
var options1 = {
title: 'Stock Performance',
width: 300,
height: 300
};

var chart1 = new google.charts.Line(document.getElementById('2dea80b0fabd43bba019dbc3ddf342aa'));
chart1.draw(data1, options1);

}
```

```html
<script src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script src="http://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="e480c510499e4bbdaa8ae8e4a1001cd8"></div>
<div id="2dea80b0fabd43bba019dbc3ddf342aa"></div>
<div id="linechart_material"></div>
```

**Option 2. Render charts synchronously**

Since `draw` function is asynchronous, we utilize `ready` event handler to draw charts sequentially, in that case multiple chart should be rendered properly as demonstrated below.

**Example**

```js
google.load('visualization', '1.1', { 'packages': ['line'] });
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);


function drawChart() {
var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
data.addColumn('date', 'Day');

data.addColumn('number', 'Company #4');
data.addColumn('number', 'Company #2');
data.addRow([new Date(2015, 11,  27), 12.7389789250395,4.10950499778125]);
data.addRow([new Date(2015, 11,  26), 6.76681987790708,8.38212726329552]);
data.addRow([new Date(2015, 11,  25), 15.7216755155109,4.36060299741132]);
data.addRow([new Date(2015, 11,  24), 7.44940381844035,3.34093286951116]);
data.addRow([new Date(2015, 11,  23), 9.02574470221333,10.0405249521325]);
data.addRow([new Date(2015, 11,  22), 11.9767397269498,5.29850781210629]);
data.addRow([new Date(2015, 11,  21), 14.5598888055235,6.3867255497662]);
data.addRow([new Date(2015, 11,  20), 12.2693184056642,3.70270192981823]);
data.addRow([new Date(2015, 11,  19), 8.29967047194935,17.0856299675469]);
data.addRow([new Date(2015, 11,  18), 12.9148372020176,4.37814835290338]);
var options = {
title: 'Stock Performance',
width: 900,
height: 500
};


var data0 = new google.visualization.DataTable();
data0.addColumn('date', 'Day');
data0.addColumn('number', 'Company #4');
data0.addRow([new Date(2015, 11,  27), 12.7389789250395]);
data0.addRow([new Date(2015, 11,  26), 6.76681987790708]);
data0.addRow([new Date(2015, 11,  25), 15.7216755155109]);
data0.addRow([new Date(2015, 11,  24), 7.44940381844035]);
data0.addRow([new Date(2015, 11,  23), 9.02574470221333]);
data0.addRow([new Date(2015, 11,  22), 11.9767397269498]);
data0.addRow([new Date(2015, 11,  21), 14.5598888055235]);
data0.addRow([new Date(2015, 11,  20), 12.2693184056642]);
data0.addRow([new Date(2015, 11,  19), 8.29967047194935]);
data0.addRow([new Date(2015, 11,  18), 12.9148372020176]);
var options0 = {
title: 'Stock Performance',
width: 300,
height: 300
};


var data1 = new google.visualization.DataTable();
data1.addColumn('date', 'Day');
data1.addColumn('number', 'Company #2');
data1.addRow([new Date(2015, 11,  27), 4.10950499778125]);
data1.addRow([new Date(2015, 11,  26), 8.38212726329552]);
data1.addRow([new Date(2015, 11,  25), 4.36060299741132]);
data1.addRow([new Date(2015, 11,  24), 3.34093286951116]);
data1.addRow([new Date(2015, 11,  23), 10.0405249521325]);
data1.addRow([new Date(2015, 11,  22), 5.29850781210629]);
data1.addRow([new Date(2015, 11,  21), 6.3867255497662]);
data1.addRow([new Date(2015, 11,  20), 3.70270192981823]);
data1.addRow([new Date(2015, 11,  19), 17.0856299675469]);
data1.addRow([new Date(2015, 11,  18), 4.37814835290338]);
var options1 = {
title: 'Stock Performance',
width: 300,
height: 300
};

var chart = new google.charts.Line(document.getElementById('linechart_material'));
google.visualization.events.addOneTimeListener(chart, 'ready', function(){
     
     var chart0 = new google.charts.Line(document.getElementById('e480c510499e4bbdaa8ae8e4a1001cd8'));
     google.visualization.events.addOneTimeListener(chart0, 'ready', function(){
         var chart1 = new google.charts.Line(document.getElementById('2dea80b0fabd43bba019dbc3ddf342aa'));
         chart1.draw(data1, options1);
     });    
     chart0.draw(data0, options0);

});
chart.draw(data, options);

}
```

```html
<script src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<div id="e480c510499e4bbdaa8ae8e4a1001cd8"></div>
<div id="2dea80b0fabd43bba019dbc3ddf342aa"></div>
<div id="linechart_material"></div>
```