# Multiple google visualization table on one page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, google-visualization

I'm having a problem with creating multiple google visualization tables on a single page. How do I dynamically generate an unknown number of google visualization tables on a single page with complete functionality?

I referenced this (almost identical) question for help [How to add two Google charts on the one page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9888920/how-to-add-two-google-charts-on-the-one-page) however Dominor Novus's solution does not help if you are not already aware, prior to the creation of the page, of the number of tables. For example, sometimes I will need to have 5 tables, sometimes I will only need to have 1.

My question is how do I dynamically create a page that will dynmically create multiple google visualization tables each with its own unique identifier. Then when a user clicks on a row in the table be able to return the row number as well as the unique identifier for the dynamically created table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to effectively come up with a solution to the problem, we must store the table data and the table object in arrays. We first create arrays for the data and the table object at the top of the page.

```
var tableData=new Array();
var table=new Array();
var tableid=0;
```

We then generate our table storing them in arrays referenced by a unique identifier. Then in order to fulfill the select functionality of the table we add a listener to the table object. We then grab the id of the containing div of the table, and take the substring of that id to discover what table has just been clicked. Then we take the row of that table as normally done using the method .getSelection(). Once we have both the row and the table id we can return those to the users based on which table and row he clicked.

```
//create dynamic number of tables
for (id=0;id<num_of_tables;id++) {
    var tableID = 'table_div' + id; //The id of the google visualization table

    //Generate the div for the google visualization table
    $('<div/>', {
        id: tableID,
        class: 'cd_table'
    }).appendTo('#tables');

    listData = data;

    if (listData[id].length>0) {
        tableData[id] = new google.visualization.DataTable();

        tableData[id].addColumn('string', 'name');
        tableData[id].addColumn('string', 'email');

        for (var i=0; i<listData[id].length; i++) {
            tableData[id].addRows(1);           
            tableData[id].setCell(i,0,listData[id][i].name);
            tableData[id].setCell(i,1,listData[id][i].email);
        }
    }

    table[id] = new google.visualization.Table(document.getElementById(tableID));
    table[id].draw(tableData[id], {showRowNumber: false, sortColumn: 0});

    google.visualization.events.addListener(table[id], 'select', function() {
        $(document).on('mousemove', '.google-visualization-table', function() { 
           tableid=$(this).closest('.cd_table').attr('id').substring(9);
        });

        var row;
        if (table[tableid].getSelection()[0] != undefined) {
            row = table[tableid].getSelection()[0].row;
            lastRowClick = row;
        } else row = lastRowClick;
        alert('table id:' + tableid + ' row:' + row);
    });
}
```

This is nearly perfect, but only works if you clicked on the table already once. We must also add a mousemove event in the initial page load jquery function, like so:

```
$(document).on('mousemove', '.google-visualization-table', function() { 
    tableid=$(this).closest('.cd_table').attr('id').substring(9);
});
```

And done. You are able to create an unlimited amount of dynamically generated google visualization tables, that can return the row clicked and the id of the table that was clicked.

Comment: I tried something similar to this, but was getting inconsistent results, such as sometimes multiple charts would display, other times not (seemingly random). Though maybe I can take another look and try the mousemove listener trick. I ended up just using a different library in the end. Thanks!

Comment: @avoliva which library did you end up using?

Comment: I ended up going with Chartist